# Why does my Python petl library appear to be missing functions?

Tags: python, etl

I'm new to Python (not new to programming) and am trying to learn both the Python language and the Petl library for some ETL work I need to do.

I'm going through some basic tutorials on petl.readthedocs.org and have come across a couple missing functions and am wondering what I'm doing wrong... Below is a screenshot of an example where the function 'fromcolumns' isn't recognized even though its featured in petl tutorials.

[image]

Comment: Version mismatch? Looks like that function was added in version 1.1.0

Comment: @JCVanHamme Yeah, looks like I have an old version. Doing a help(petl) tells me that the version number is 1.0.11. How do I go about updating this?

Comment: `pip install --upgrade petl` should do it. If not, `pip uninstall petl` then `pip install petl==1.1.0`

Comment: @JCVanHamme Thanks that worked! I knew about `pip install` but was trying to run it from the Python Interpreter rather than the Windows command line which obviously wasn't working....